# Angularjs, ng-click on font awesome span not working, but works on button

Tags: angularjs, font-awesome

I have this code:

```
<input is-password="checkPassword" autocomplete="off" required
       ng-model="vm.simulate.rutDeudor" type="password" minlength="3"
       id="rut-deudor-field" tabindex="2"
       ng-attr-type="{{ isPassword ? 'password' : 'text' }}">
<button ng-click="checkPassword=!checkPassword">Mostrar</button>
<span ng-click="checkPassword=!checkPassword" class="fa fa-lg fa-eye"> 
</span>
```

The idea is to use `span` and not `button`, I don't know why with button works but not with span.

This is the controller:

```
angular.module('app.factoringCotizarDocs')
.controller('sincronizarCarpetaTributariaModalCtrl', sincronizarCarpetaTributariaModalCtrl)
.directive('isPassword', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope: {
      isPassword: '=isPassword'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('isPassword', function(a, b){
        element.attr('type', a ? 'text' : 'password')
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` works well with `span`. So I think the problem is with some conflicts in your project.

Here is a <kbd>[demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Beak9C92hkLguSUW)</kbd>